# click on picture i when it name is presently in array [i]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a folder containing some pictures ordered alphabetically (in large icon mode) and I have them listed in an sorted array (equally alphabetically) using the Java code below.

```
public class FileNamesInArrayHighlighted {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {


        File folder = new File("C:\\MyFolder");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        int N = listOfFiles.length;
        String [] s = new String [N];
        String [] sorted_s = new String [N];
        Arrays.sort(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        {
              s[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }  

        sorted_s = s;

        }

    }
```

I would like to know how I can create a second loop as below, that will click on each of the associated file/picture in the folder.

```
for (int j =0; j<N; j++) 
{

     //Click/select sorted_s[i] in its folder

 }
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: When you say click on the images, do you mean that the code should open those images?

Comment: Not to open the image but just select the image in its folder (in the background and also without leaving my present screen).